# java ID check method

Tags: java, methods

Im trying to write a method that takes in an ID of the form "xxxx-xxxx" (x being any number 1-9) and checks to see if the ID entered is valid. For example, 1111-1111 would be valid, but 111p-1111 or 11111-1111 would not be. However, after I have written this method, it comes out as true even when the ID is of the form 111p-1111.

```
public static boolean idCheck(String ID){
    char[] idChar = ID.toCharArray();
    boolean firstHalf = false;
    boolean secHalf = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){//Check first half 
        if ((idChar[i] > 47 && idChar[i] < 58)){//Checks ascii vals to see if valid ID
            firstHalf = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 5; i < idChar.length; ++i){//Check second half
        if ((idChar[i] > 47 && idChar[i] < 58)){//Checks ascii vals to see if valid ID
            secHalf = true;
        }
    }

    //If all values are valid, returns true.
    if (firstHalf == true && secHalf == true && idChar[4] == '-' && ID.length() == 9){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's because if one of the part contains a number, you set your boolean variable to true. Your better bet is probably to set firstHalf and secondHalf as true, then in your for loop if it's not a number, set the boolean variable to false and break the loop. If you are familiar with regular expressions, you could use matches with a regex saying "match 4 digits - 4 digits"

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements only look at one number to determine if it sets the boolean to true.  So if `any` of the numbers in each half are valid, the boolean will be set to true.

You are probably better off using regular expressions. [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) is a great resource to get started! :)

Something like:

```
[1-9]{4}-[1-9]{4} (You can also use \d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression would be much simpler in this case:

```
\d{4}-\d{4}
```

In Java:

```
static boolean idCheck(String id) {
    return id.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{4}");
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, here's an explanation:

- `\d` **Match a digit 0-9**

  - `{4}` **Repeat last token 4 times (matches 4 digits)**
- `-` **Match a hyphen literally**
- `\d` **Match a digit 0-9**

  - `{4}` **Repeat last token 4 times (matches 4 digits)**

Answer (score 0):

You only check if there is at least one character that matches, not if any of the input characters are failing.

To have a quick solution that is easy to understand for any Java developer after you you could use a Regex and check if your input matches:

```
public static boolean idCheck(String id){
  return Pattern.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{4}", id);
}
```

If you want to keep your way of checking you should start with `true` `boolean`s and check if they stay true.

```
boolean firstHalf = true;
boolean secHalf = true;
```

and therefrom use `firstHalf &= true` for your updates and use a `else{ firstHalf = false; }` branch.

To keep your method I would prefer to always back out fast if you know the result:

```
public static boolean idCheck(String id)
{
    //check length
    if (id.length() != 9)
        return false;

    char[] idChar = id.toCharArray();
    //check for dash
    if (idChar[4] != '-')
        return false;

    //check first half
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (!(idChar[i] > 47 && idChar[i] < 58))
            return false;
    }

    //check second half
    for (int i = 5; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        if (!(idChar[i] > 47 && idChar[i] < 58))
            return false;
    }
}
```